# I accidentally chmod 700 /etc. And now I became I have no name user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, chmod

Today, I accidentally do this in my web server,

```
sudo chmod 700 /etc
```

And now, I can no longer access to /etc folder. Because I am denied from using the /etc folder, I can no longer use the sudo command, and I notice that I am logging in as I have no name!@ip xxxxx:.

I tried to

```
pkexec chmod 400 /etc/sudoers
```

and I was ask to Authenticate as Ubuntu and enter password. I entered the correct password, (I am sure I entered the correct password, as I wrote it down when I created, no doubts), but the authentication still failed, and system said "Error executing command as another user: Not authorized".

Can anyone guide me to fix the problem?

Comment: Do you have a working root user?  What you likely will have to do is boot into a live environment, and as the root user there, fix the permissions.

Comment: the root for Ubuntu is Ubuntu, and I've been using that to work on the server. And now when I use Ubuntu to login, it just say I have no name.

Comment: Isn't Ubuntu a sudoers user?

Comment: Yes, and I sudo chmod the /etc folder. And now things are not working out. I am now detaching the volume from instance and putting it in a new instance to see if I can access the old volume's /etc folder.